# Giving a fixed width and height to a container vs providing constraints via a BoxConstraints class

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout, flutter-web, flutter-animation, flutter-container

In the `Container` widget in flutter,

**What is the difference between giving it a fixed `height` and `width`  AND providing it `BoxConstraints` for the `constraints` property?**.

Is it either providing a ***width + height*** or ***constraints***? Can they be both provided at the same time? What is the difference?

I also looked at the [official docs](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/Container-class.html) which refers to the `Container` widget and in there, right under the heading called *Layout Behavior* they mention what happens when different combinations of width and height and constraints do? (But I do not understand how they differ)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**TLDR: They do the same thing**

**Long Answer:**
If you take a look at the `Container`'s code you could see that the `width` and `height` you've provided actually gets turned into a `BoxConstraints`. `Container` will use that `BoxConstraints` to set its constraints. Here's a October 2021 snippet of the `Container`'s constructor:

```
  Container({
    Key? key,
    this.alignment,
    this.padding,
    this.color,
    this.decoration,
    this.foregroundDecoration,
    double? width,
    double? height,
    BoxConstraints? constraints,
    this.margin,
    this.transform,
    this.transformAlignment,
    this.child,
    this.clipBehavior = Clip.none,
  }) : // *Removed the asserts it made to make this snippet shorter
       // Important part is here
       constraints =
        (width != null || height != null)
          ? constraints?.tighten(width: width, height: height)
            ?? BoxConstraints.tightFor(width: width, height: height)
          : constraints,
       super(key: key);
```

Here is a portion of the `Container`'s build method:

```
// Parts of the code removed to shorten snippet
if (constraints != null)
  current = ConstrainedBox(constraints: constraints!, child: current);
// Parts of the code removed to shorten snippet
return current!;
```

Comment: In `BoxConstrains`, there are properties called `minWidth` and `maxWidth` etc... right? But when giving a `width`  to a `Container`, we only provide one single `width` right? If they both are the same how come we can only set one `width` and in `BoxConstraints` there exists two properties called `minWidth` and `maxWidth`? (This is not clear to me)

Comment: @gfit21x They added the width and height attributes for simplicity. Most of the time, there is no need to set any min and max width. Using a `BoxConstraint` will lengthen the amount of code we have to type just to set the width and height of the container.

Comment: @gfit21x When you set `height: 20` it gets converted to `minHeight: 20, maxHeight: 20` (tight constraint).

Comment: I got a confused a bit more now cause I was on a call with someone I know who does flutter and when I asked the same question from him he said "`height` + `width` sets the dimensions of the parent widget whereas `constraints` tell child widgets how they should be positioned"....
So they aren't exactly the same thing though the answer mentions that they are? 